# Invoking function in iframe on same-domain, supporting Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an event on the parent page that triggers a javascript function, which in turn calls another function on the child iframe. Both pages are in the same domain and I have verified this by having javascript display the document.domain in both pages simultaneously.

This is what has worked for years, and is suggested in similar topics:
    windows.frames["iframeID"].somefunction();
That ceased working with Internet Explorer version 8.0.7600.16385
It does work on Internet Explorer version 8.0.6001.18702

I've tried replacing it with each of these and the result was the same:
    iframeName.somefunction();
    document.frames("iframeName").somefunction();
    top.frames[0].somefunction();

The error given is "Access is denied" and references the first bit of code in somefunction(), however, somefunction() works fine if called within the iframe itself.

Is there a new "proper" way to call functions within an iframe from the parent? Is there a workaround on the code side (I can't control the user's browser)?

EDIT: Here is the internal function:
    function somefunction() {
    somebutton.click();
    }
If instead I use "alert('something');", it works without error.

EDIT2: Newer version, as well as IE9's Beta have extended this to also defeat the hacky workaround, so I'm back to dead in the water.

EDIT3: I had forgotten about this until someone posted nearly a year later. This is the workaround I ended up with:

Parent calls iframename.badscripthack();
Child in iframe has function:
function badscripthack()
{
   document.getElementById("OffscreenTextField").focus();
}
function submitthis()
{
   document.getElementById("SubmitButton").click();
}
And the tag:

As the name implies, this is a bad hack, but it was necessary. Of course, it doesn't answer the "proper" way to handle it. It has worked since, and nobody "back-tabs" to trigger it accidentally (and if they did, the consequences are merely saving a form early).

Answer (score 1):

**Parent Html**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function CallFrame()
  {
        var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
    if(frame)
    {
           frame.contentWindow.Show();
        }
  } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> I am Parent </h1>
<input type="button" onclick="CallFrame()" value="Call Frame function" /><br/>
<iframe id="myframe" src="Frame.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Frame.Html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Show()
{
alert("Called");
}
</script>
</head>
```

```
<h1> I am IFrame</h1>
<input type="button" onclick="Show();" value="Call Own function">
</body>
</html>
```

**Tested in FireFox and IE8**

Comment: The problem was that it was a submit event. The alert event worked up until an update a few weeks after the initial post. I'm editing in the current workaround, which has worked since then. After two months of no replies here I had forgotten about the post.